# Prove $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}2^k \binom{n}{k}=3^n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I need to prove that $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}2^k \binom{n}{k}=3^n$$

for any integer $n$. Induction seems to be the straightforward solution, but I have failed at it:

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}2^k \binom{n}{k}=\\\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k \binom{n}{k}+2^n=\\ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k \binom{n-1}{k}\frac{n}{n-k}+2^n=\\ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k \binom{n-1}{k}\left(1+\frac{k}{n-k}\right)+2^n=\\
3^{n-1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k \binom{n-1}{k}\frac{k}{n-k}+2^n=\\
\end{align}

The last step is the induction hypothesis and the base of induction is trivial. I'm not sure what to do next.

There might also be a combinatorical proof: the expression on the left is the amount of ways to pick some balls out of $n$ balls and color each one of them in either of 2 colors. However, I do not follow how that is equal to $3^n$.

Comment: Hint : Expand $(2+1)^n$

Comment: As per binomial theorem $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r}x^r$$ put x=2.

Comment: Here is a combinatorial proof.  $3^n$ counts the number of strings of length $n$ made from the elements $0,1,2$.  

On the other hand, any such string that contain $k$ non-zero elements can be constructed as follows:

- Select $k$ out of $n$ poisitions in which to place the non-zero elements; there are $\binom nk$ such choices
- Select a string of length $k$ made from the elements $1,2$ that will be placed into these positions; there are $2^k$ such choices
- Fill the rest of the string with $0$'s; no choice needs to be made here.

Comment: Thus, the number of these strings that contain $k$ non-zero elements is $2^k \binom nk$.  Conclude that 
$$
3^n = \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom nk
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an argument using the binomial expansion, which can be proven using induction or other arguments:
$$(1 + x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{C}$$
Let $x = 2$ to get your answer.